# CRM 2011 PlugIn on appointment delete not fetching required attendees

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Can anyone say that how to fetch the '**requiredattendees**' of appointment when appointment gets deleted. 
On delete of appointment I need to perform update on those attendees. I am not getting values in that party list either on PRE or POST.

Even PreImage entity is not capturing the information of only that 'requiredattendees' field, rest fields are ok in that PreImage entity.

Can anyone say that what I am doing wrong ?

Thank You very much.

Comment: The entity image itself will not have related records, you need to fetch the related records.

Comment: I have tried this, it not worked. Main issue is that when I debug it, it works fine..when I don't debug, it does not work. :(

Comment: Looks like data issue to me, are you using the same record in both cases? logically it should matter if you are debugging it or not.

Comment: No, it is not data issue. you need profiled error tod ebug the plugin and when profiler is on, delete operation will get completed and that record still exist in CRM, you can refresh the grid you will get the record. Now when I debug it fetches the values from same record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the list of child records in a `PreValidation` plugin as cascading deletes/disassociations *may* occur before `PreOperation`.

Assuming you transnational integrity you should gather this information in `PreValidation` and save it (`IPluginExecutionContext.SharedVariables` is a good place to save the guids.) In a `PreOperation` or `PostOperation` plugin you can execute your logic against the list of required attendee guids you stored.

Comment: I never tried this i.e PreValidation, first time I will do and will update here .

Comment: I tried it and it is really working on 'PreValidation' stage of Appointment. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have registered the plugin on `Delete` `Preoperation`

```
var appointment = pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] as EntityReference;
var response = organizationService.Retrieve("appointment", appointment.Id, new ColumnSet("requiredattendees"));
var requiredAttendees = response.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("requiredattendees");

foreach (var attendee in requiredAttendees.Entities)
{
       //your logic
}
```

Comment: I have tried this first time and it did not work, so tried for PreImage and that also not worked. :( I can try the above of above approach. Will update here.

Comment: I created a plugin just to test this out and worked for me. Did you register your plugin on pre-op?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. In your case, you are able to fetch the partylist of field 'requiredattendees' without debugging plugin registered on PreOperation of Appointment(Delete) in sync mode ?